# Automatically recognize that a variable has been factorized before in a regression in R

Tags: r, regression, categorical-data

I want to write my own predict function but face some problems doing so. 
At first I wrote a code for a logistic regression. Before you can run the logistic regression, you have to manually factorize all variables that need to be factorized. When it comes to the predict function, I want that it
automatically recognizes that I have factorized a variable before. This is necessary for the correct calculation of the linear predictor.

I am able to manually factorize the variable rank again in the code below. Then the mat matrix gives the correct values for all variables, so I can multiply them with the estimated coefficients to get the linear predictor. However, I want that this is recognized automatically.

```
newdata = data.frame( gre= 300, gpa = 2, rank = "2")

newdata$rank <- factor(newdata$rank, levels = 1:4)

newdata
newdata$rank

mat <- model.matrix(~ gre + gpa + rank, newdata)
mat
```

I have already checked whether the x variables of my logistic regression object are factors but they aren't.

Is there any way that I can check whether a variable has been factorized before?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use `is.factor`

Comment: @yarnabrina thanks for your answer. My initial dataset is called mydata. I can check whether mydata$rank is a factor by is.factor(mydata$rank). But everybody calls their dataset differently. So this code won't work for everybody. Is there maybe a more general solution? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I thought of something like a function that can recognize a factorized variable in the output of the regression.

Comment: Is there an argument in your function that takes dataset? If yes, and if that's called `my_dataset`, then I think you can safely use `is.factor(my_dataset$rank)` inside the function.

Comment: Or `sapply(my_dataset, is.factor)`. This returns a logical vector with one element per column.

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
#fit an example model
DF <- mtcars
DF$carb <- factor(DF$carb)
fit <- lm(drat ~ mpg + carb, data = DF)

#classes of the model terms
classes <- attr(terms(fit), "dataClasses")
#     drat       mpg      carb 
#"numeric" "numeric"  "factor" 

new.data <- mtcars
#set variables in new.data to factor if they are factors in the model
new.data[, names(classes)[classes == "factor"]] <- 
  lapply(new.data[, names(classes)[classes == "factor"], drop = FALSE], as.factor)
```